# Get size of queue in twilio from rest call in php without using library

Tags: php, rest, curl, yii, twilio

My php/Yii application interacts with twilio. I know the sid of a queue. I want to get the current size of that queue. The thing is that I can't use the twilio php library (I don't want to get into the details). I'm using curl, but I keep getting 401 errors.

This is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl,array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountId/Queues/QUeueID.json',
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'token:{AuthToken}'));
curl_exec($curl);
```

I don't what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to follow the documentation:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue

EDIT: I turned it into a get request, from a post request.

Also, I got a 401 unauthorized error, not a 411. Sorry about that. Typo.

SECOND EDIT:

So, I figured it out in a conversation with Kevin. Turns out that I needed:

```
CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'AccountID:Token'
```

Comment: Is that a typo in QueueID (capitalization) I see?

Comment: No, the first two characters are QU capitalized, so that's not a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to retrieve the size of a queue, you want to make a GET request, not a POST. It looks like you are setting CURLOPT_POST in your curl request.

Comment: Thanks, you're right that I should have been using GET. Still, it doesn't help me

Comment: can you update the example with the latest code you are using? a 411 indicates you are sending a Content-Length header when you shouldn't be.

Comment: A 401 Unauthorized indicates there is a problem with your credentials. This is a different error than a 411. Check that you are including the correct Account SID and Auth Token.

Comment: Should be something like `USERPWD, AC123:456`

Comment: Could you expand on that last comment? Right now it's literally what you see, with {AuthToken} and my token where it says token.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24791/discussion-between-kevin-burke-and-nielmalhotra)

Comment: I'll accept your answer because you answered my question in chat